# How to check a JSON object Boolean value that then creates a webpage from a php template if True

Tags: php, json, templates

I have a json file.

```
{
    "whitepapers": {
        "1": {
            "name": "The Title of the Doc",
            "file": "the-title-of-the-doc",
            "asset_description": "blah blah",
            "image": "/img.png",
            "formId": "xxx",
            "confirmation": true
        },
        "0": {
            "name": "The Title of the Doc 2",
            "file": "the-title-of-the-doc-2",
            "asset_description": "blah blah",
            "image": "/img.png",
            "formId": "xxx",
            "confirmation": true
        }
    },
```

there is a `page-handler.php` that already takes information from this json file and creates pages from them:

```
if (strpos($shortPage, 'whitepapers') !== false) {           // test for Whitepapers overview page
        require $contentPath . 'resources_whitepapers.php';
    } else if (($aPosition=strpos($shortPage, 'whitepaper')) !== false) {  // test for whitepaper asset page & grab where in string if positive
        $aString = mb_substr($shortPage, ($aPosition + 10));     // strip everything from the string up to the end of the found string
        $aString = ltrim($aString, '/');                         // remove the preceding "/" if it exists

        $json_string = $contentPath . 'asset-manifest.json';     // point to the asset manifest list [in json format] TODO: error handling here
        $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);             // load it into memory
        $obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);                      // decode it into an array

        foreach ($obj['whitepapers'] as $key => $value) {        // Find the parent of our string's key/value pair in the multidimensional json array
            foreach ($value as $_key => $_value) {
                if ($_key === 'file' && $_value === $aString) {  // look for the asset string value in the 'file' key
                    $match = $key;                               // found a match, grab the pair's parent array
        }}}

        if ($match >= 0) {                                           // found a match in the manifest, render the page
            require  $contentPath . 'whitepaper-template.php'; 
        } else {                                                // can't find a match in the manifest
            include $errorPagePath;                             // return a 404 page and handle the error
        }

    } else if....
```

The dev who made this originally is no longer here so I can't ask him to walk me through it.

I want to be able to check if `"confirmation": true` and then funnel into a `confirmation-temaplte.php` like how the above funnels into a `whitepaper-template.php` and then else `"confirmation": false` it doesn't do anything

I've tried copying the code over from `page-handler.php` into a `else if ("confirmation":true){blah}` and making a `confirmation-template.php` but I wasn't sure if I was targeting `"confirmation"` correctly.

Then I noticed it started messing up the other pages that are dependent on the json file.  It seems when I make a `confirmation-template.php` page it messes up the other pages using a `xxx-template.php` file and I'm unsure why.

As you see, I'm a bit new at PHP Templating and JSON information access.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($obj['whitepapers'] as $key => $value) {        // Find the parent of our string's key/value pair in the multidimensional json array
if ($value['confirmation'] ?? false) {
  // here Is your confirmation === true
}
            foreach ($value as $_key => $_value) {
                if ($_key === 'file' && $_value === $aString) {  // look for the asset string value in the 'file' key
                    $match = $key;                               // found a match, grab the pair's parent array
        }}}
```